# show a bootstrap modal when user press option in menu

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I do have created a menu in bootstrap and want to show a modal when the user hits this option:

```
<li><a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Asistencia técnica</a></li>
```

the modal I want to show is this

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalAgrupacion" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h3>INSAFORP</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4>Evento Libre Gestión</h4>
                <p>Solicitud ingresada con exito. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger">Cerrar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You open a Bootstrap modal with what is called a trigger. In your case, all you have to do is add two attributes on your a tag like so:

```
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAgrupacion"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Asistencia técnica</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was easy, just had to add an id to the specific li element and after that use jQuery to capture the click event to show the modal